# Function that determines and returns the programming language of a given file

Tags: files, functions, compile

I'm working on some compiler shortcuts:
I want to write a function `(cmp FILE-NAME &optional args)` that will use `FILE-NAME` and args to construct the appropriate `COMMAND` to call `(compile COMMAND)` with.

For example: `(cmp "Test.java" "-Xlint:all")` will run `(compile "javac Test.java -Xlint:all")`

This is mostly so I can write my default args that I'll want to compile specific programs with.

As part of this, I'll need my function to determine the programming language of the given file. I could do this with some simple expressions like:

```lisp
(setq file-ext (substring file-name (string-match "\.[^.]*$" file-name)))
(setq programming-language (cond ((equal ".java" file-ext) "java")
                                 ((equal ".c" file-ext) "c")
                                 ((equal ".sc" file-ext) "scala")))
```

This would work but I'd have to add a new condition for any new programming language, and it seems overkill because I know that Emacs is already able to determine a file's programming language: it's how it knows to, for example, load `java-mode` when I open a Java file.

So I know it's probably a simple question, but I can't find documentation to show me *how* Emacs determines a file's programming language, and how I can leverage that same function for my own customization.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Emacs's ability to "determine a file's programming language" is based on a simple list, just a bit more complicated than the one you conteplated. Do `C-h v auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: Do you maybe want to use the external `file` utility?  E.g. in your shell, run `file <path>`.  That's the best way I know of to identify the purpose of a file.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs *doesn't* determine a file's programming language. What it does is look at the file buffer's **major mode**, and that mode is often (by default) associated with a given programming language.

See (`C-h v`) variable **`auto-mode-alist`** for the association of file-name suffixes with major modes.

So the first question to ask yourself is this: *Do you really need to know the "programming language"?* Or does it suffice to know the major mode?

Note that there's no real way (no way possible) to know/obtain the name of a programming language from a major mode.  You can try various ad hoc means of getting it, by parsing some doc or function/variable names, but there's no real association that's dependable.

See if you can do what you're (really) trying to accomplish just by using the `major-mode`.  That you have access to.

See the Elisp manual, node [Major Mode Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html) for some info about major modes.

Comment: Thank you! The auto-mode-alist looks like a great option: it's basically a pre-filled-out list of what I was looking for.
I'm looking into the major-mode and I can definitely see its use, but if I'm understanding it correctly, its value will depend on what my current open buffer is. So if I want to compile "desktop/Test.java," I'd have to open the file first for the mode to switch to java-mode

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, in that last part. You can get the mode for a file extension from `auto-mode-alist`. You can get to all info about that mode from `C-h f <the-mode-name>`. From that `*Help*` buffer you have a link to the source code that defines the mode.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. I can use `auto-mode-alist` to get the mode for any file (or at least most of them: it's a pretty big list). I was wondering if I could use `major-mode` similarly, but it seems `major-mode` is defined for the current buffer, so I could only use it when I'm trying to compile the file in my current buffer

Comment: @andy_programs `(with-current-buffer BUF major-mode)` or `(buffer-local-value 'major-mode BUF)` gives you the `major-mode` value in the buffer BUF.